# Way to make exercise numbers to the left of text easier than minipages?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, environments, exercises

I am experimenting with typing up solutions to textbook exercises in a way that looks really nice. I want exercise numbers to appear to the left of all text, and dividers between problems to be wider than text but not go as far as the exercise numbers. The way I'm currently doing this is by stacking minipages for exercises and text next to each other.

[image: example]

The picture is of the first page (the rectangles are put there by Overleaf because there are internal links between parts of the document - it doesn't show up in the actual pdf), and below is some code which reproduces the first problem:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scale=0.92]{tgschola}

\def\vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\color{Cerulean}\underline{Chapter One (3-18): \textbf{Classical Groups I}}} \vspace{0.75cm}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[l]{0.082\linewidth}
~~~~~{\color{Plum}(1)}\vspace{6.4cm}
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.9\linewidth}
The usual linear algebra argument applies even if $F=\mathbf{H}$. Given any right $F$-linear endomorphism $A$ of $F^n$, define its matrix by $[A]=[a_{ij}]$, where $Ae_i=\sum_{j=1}^n e_ja_{ij}$ for $i=1,...,n$, so that $Av=[A]v$ identically: 
\vspace{-0.35cm}\begin{equation*} Av=A\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n e_iv_i\Big)=\sum_{i=1}^n(Ae_i)v_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n e_ja_{ij}\Big)v_j=\sum_{j=1}^n e_j\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}v_j\Big)=[A]v. \end{equation*} 

\vspace{-0.36cm} Therefore the identities $(A+B)v=Av+Bv$ and $(AB)v=A(Bv)$ imply $[A+B]=[A]+[B]$ and $[AB]=[A][B]$, plus $(\lambda A)v=\lambda(Av)$ for scalars $\lambda\in F$ implies $[\lambda A]=\lambda[A]$, so $A\mapsto [A]$ is an algebra homomorphism $\mathrm{End}_FF^n\to M_n(F)$ (of $\mathbf{C}$-algebras if $F=\mathbf{C}$ else as $\mathbf{R}$-algebras). Indeed, $Av=[A]v$ implies $A\mapsto[A]$ is a one-to-one correspondence, so this is an isomorphism, which restricted to units yields the same for $\mathrm{GL}(n,F)$.
\end{minipage} \\ 

\quad{\color{orange}\vhrulefill} \vspace{0.3cm}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this makes for unwieldy code and a lot of work. Note the vspace in the exercise number's minipages have to be adjusted to the size of the text in that solution. And I have to split exercises between multiple pages whenever they run over, which means if I want to go back and change things earlier in the document I more or less have to change things around the entire document to fill up the pages right, which seems like a poor idea to do for the whole thing.

Is there a good way to "automate" this template so it's not as much work and I can go back and change something within the document later without having to change everything after it as well?

(I looked for the first couple pages of tags and picked what looked most relevant, but perhaps others have a better idea of what to tag this with.)

Comment: Please, can you put a minimal working example i.e. a full complete code in tex?

Comment: @Sebastiano I stripped it to some code which reproduces the first problem (without hyperref and some other packages) and illustrates how I did it with minipages.

Comment: For a single line you can use `\makebox[<width>][l]{...}`.  BTW, you are adding an extra space between the minipages.  Also, [l] is not a valid minipage option [tcb].

Comment: @runway44, below egreg posted a nice solution. However, you should specify whether or not you'll use oneside or twoside with extarticle, where you want your blue text, how the even sides should look like etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try and use as less formatting instructions in the document as possible: using properly defined environments and commands will ensure uniformity across the whole document.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scale=0.92]{tgschola}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{exercise}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0.1\textwidth}{}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\color{Plum}(#1)\enspace}\ignorespaces
}{\end{adjustwidth}\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\newcommand\vhrulefill{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \nointerlineskip
  \hbox{\hspace{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth-0.5em}%
    \color{orange}\vrule width\dimexpr0.9\textwidth+0.5em\relax height 0.4pt
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
  \addvspace{\topsep}%
}

\newcommand{\exegroup}[2]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\textcolor{Cerulean}{#1: \textbf{#2}}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}

\newcommand{\numberfield}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\HH}{\numberfield{H}}% quaternions
\newcommand{\CC}{\numberfield{C}}% complex
\newcommand{\RR}{\numberfield{R}}% real

\begin{document}

\exegroup{Chapter One (3-18)}{Classical Groups I}

\begin{exercise}{1}
The usual linear algebra argument applies even if $F=\HH$. 
Given any right $F$-linear endomorphism $A$ of $F^n$, define its 
matrix by $[A]=[a_{ij}]$, where $Ae_i=\sum_{j=1}^n e_ja_{ij}$ for 
$i=1,\dots,n$, so that $Av=[A]v$ identically: 
\begin{equation*}
Av=A\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n e_iv_i\Bigr)=
\sum_{i=1}^n(Ae_i)v_i=
\sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl(\,\sum_{j=1}^n e_ja_{ij}\Bigr)v_j=
\sum_{j=1}^n e_j\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}v_j\Bigr)=[A]v.
\end{equation*} 
Therefore the identities $(A+B)v=Av+Bv$ and $(AB)v=A(Bv)$ imply 
$[A+B]=[A]+[B]$ and $[AB]=[A][B]$, plus $(\lambda A)v=\lambda(Av)$ 
for scalars $\lambda\in F$ implies $[\lambda A]=\lambda[A]$, so 
$A\mapsto [A]$ is an algebra homomorphism $\End_FF^n\to M_n(F)$ 
(of $\CC$-algebras if $F=\CC$ else as $\RR$-algebras). 
Indeed, $Av=[A]v$ implies $A\mapsto[A]$ is a one-to-one correspondence, 
so this is an isomorphism, which restricted to units yields the same 
for $\GL(n,F)$.
\end{exercise}

\vhrulefill

\begin{exercise}{2}
The usual linear algebra argument applies even if $F=\mathbf{H}$.
Given any right $F$-linear endomorphism $A$ of $F^n$, define its
matrix by $[A]=[a_{ij}]$, where $Ae_i=\sum_{j=1}^n e_ja_{ij}$ for
$i=1,\dots,n$, so that $Av=[A]v$ identically:
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Have also a look at the changes I did on the formulas: `...` should be `\dots`, `\Big` should be either `\Bigl` or `\Bigr`; follow a big open parentheses with `\,` if there's a summation with bounds after it. I defined commands for GL, End and the number (skew) fields.

[image]

Comment: +1 Good solution. // See my commetns to the question.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to modify these commands to do hyperref stuff pretty well too.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the tasks environment?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scale=0.92]{tgschola}

\def\vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\def\vhrulefilled{\>\>\>{\color{orange}\vhrulefill}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task first task
    \end{tasks}
    \vhrulefilled
    \begin{tasks}[resume]
        \task second task   
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

You can tweak the spacing for the line in the definition of \vhrulefilled.